# Outlook backup (OST - PST Files)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, exchange

Good Morning,
I have a simple question.
The Corporate allow us 500Mb of space per User on the Exchange Server. I need to backup the mail to a local server incrementally and hourly.
What can I do? I was thinking about making a script that store every single message, but I'm sure that is not the right approach.

Comment: Local server as in your own PC HDD? You can use some program like Mailstore to do that if you like (assuming you are on Windows machine). Another option that is usually preferred is to use the Archive function which usually take it off your quota.

Comment: No, it's a File Server in the network, but the Exchange Server is located somewhere else... Mailstore can do it programmatically?

Comment: You could use the same program to do the same. Basically the [MailStore](https://www.mailstore.com/) program can run without being installed (just keeping it all in the same folder and it will run from that folder) and it can archive mail for you. Mailstore can check the mail directly (imap / archive your outlook / thunderbird) and save it in its special format (but you can also export it out as needed) Note: Not affiliated with the maker. Have used them in the past and very happy with the result.

Comment: SO I think you solution is Working well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the Outlook's built-in [AutoArchive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/830119/description-of-the-autoarchive-feature-in-outlook) feature. It does exactly what you want.